# LibreSSL SSL_connect: Broken pipe in connection to bitbucket.org:443

Tags: github, bitbucket, github-desktop, libressl

I used to pull and push bitbucket repos using GitHub desktop earlier, but for the last couple of days, I started getting this error and I'm unbale to push or pull my changes.

```
fatal: unable to access 'https://bitbucket.org/<<<Repo Link>>>/': LibreSSL SSL_connect: Broken pipe in connection to bitbucket.org:443
```

This issue seems only when I use github desktop, I can log in to my bitbucket repo in the browser and see all the files without any issues.

Answer (score 0):

**git config http.sslverify false**

solved the problem.